# getting error calling WCF SOAP web service through PHP

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I have a WCF web service hosted on IIS. It can be called through .net with no problem. but when I try to call it via PHP I get This error

object(SoapFault)#5  "Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="web service URL"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
   $X = new X ([
    'Card'  => '53535',
    'Terminal' => '43534534',
    'Amount'     => '1000',
    'OrderId'    => '1',
    'ReturnUrl'  => 'test url',
    'Password'   => 'D414305754BE7625CA70D',
    'MobileNo'   => '03003030',
    'AdditionalData' => 'test' ]);
$request_key = $X ->request(2, 1000, 'http://');

class WebServicePaymentRequest
{
public $Card  = "53535";
public $Terminal = "43534534";
public $Amount     = "1000";
public $OrderId    = "1";
public $ReturnUrl  = "test url";
public $Password   = "D414305754BE7625CA70D";
public $MobileNo   = "03003030";
}

class X  {

private $Card;
private $Terminal;
private $Amount;
private $OrderId;
private $ReturnUrl;
private $Password;
private $MobileNo;
private $AdditionalData;
private $Token;


private $wsdl_url = 'https://XXX/WebServices/PaymentUtils.svc?wsdl';


public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->Card      = $params['Card'];
    $this->Terminal     = $params['Terminal'];
    $this->Password       = $params['Password'];
    $this->Amount         = $params['Amount'];
    $this->OrderId        = $params['OrderId'];
    $this->ReturnUrl      = $params['ReturnUrl'];
    $this->MobileNo       = $params['MobileNo'];
    $this->AdditionalData = $params['AdditionalData'];

}


public function request($order_id, $amount, $callback)
{
    $options = array(
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "exceptions" => false,
        "encoding"=> 'UTF-8' 
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl_url, $options);

   $obj = new WebServicePaymentRequest;

   $obj->Amount = $amount; // Output the property
   $obj->OrderId = $order_id;
   $obj->ReturnUrl = $callback;

   $result = $client->PaymentRequest($obj);

echo $result;
 var_dump($result);

  $result = json_decode($result, true);
   $this->Token = $result['Token']; 
} 
} 
?>
```

I tried every solution in stackoverflow and other websites. but it did not work .

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I don know PHP, but from the error it appears that the client expects SOAP 1.1 (`text/xml`), while your server is sending SOAP 1.2 (`application/soap+xml`). Are you sure you've generated your client code against the correct wsdl?

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I found out that Soapclient does not support WCF in php @Hintham i solved the problem by sending Xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that Soapclient does not support WCF in PHP .I solved the problem by Posting Xml as Body with SoapAction header to The Url. I used SoapUi to get the Xml , and then postman to get the result.